# Data access class in iPhone/iPad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, database, cocoa-touch, sqlite

Now I have a few classes that work with database. I wonder would it be better to have one (Data Access Layer, singleton) class that contain CRUD methods, database connection logic etc?

Answer (score 0):

yes, you could use a singleton for that but why not use core data instead?

Comment: When I did my app I didn't know about core data. So I dont know what is better to fix code core data or singleton class.

Comment: Core Data provides pre-built classes and tools for data management. You build your custom code on top of this basic set of functionality. I would go for core data.